# how to check that fbmessanger is installed or not in iOS using facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

I have integrated the facebook SDK in my iOS application and its working good, the only problem I am having is that if the facebook messanger app is not installed then app crashes is there any method in facebook SDK so I can check that whether it is installed or not

Answer (score 1):

check url scheme of FB messenger like code below. (Swift)

```
let post = String(format: "fb-messenger://")
        let canOpenURL = UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: post)!)
        if (canOpenURL)
        {
            //FB Messanger Installed
        }
        else
        {
           //FB Messanger Not Installed
        }
```

**Also, starting at iOS 9 you must include LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in your info.plist.**

[image: Add IN Info.plist]

Answer (score 0):

check url scheme of FB messenger like code below.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://messaging?"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
   //fb messenger is installed
}
else{
     //fb messenger not installed
   }
```